# Scale body and everything in it with solid 3:4 aspect ratio to fit window

Tags: html, css, containers, scale, aspect-ratio

I was wondering how I could scale the `<body>` (or `<div id="container"`) and everything in it to always fit the window with an aspect ratio of 3:4.

So I want my entire `<body>` to act similar to a background-image that's set to contain.

It this possible?

Fyi it's for a native ipad app prototype that should always be ratio 768:1024 (same as 3:4)

Comment: You may get the results you need working with the <meta> tag in html to set your viewport size. [Description of meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). For instance: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.75">`

Comment: We don't write up code here, so make an effort of your own and if it does not work as intended, come back and we try help out